# How do I get and update an AngularJS object in an array, if I have it's id value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Assume I have this array of Objects:

```
ctrl.posts = [Object, Object, Object]
```

Each object looks similar to this:

```
{id:1, post:"post", likes:2}
```

These objects are binded to the front-end like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in ctrl.posts">
    <span ng-bind="post.post"></span>
    <span ng-bind="post.likes"></span>
</div>
```

From the back-end, I receive an id to a function x, like so:

```
functionx(id)
```

what I have to do is update the item in `ctrl.posts` whose `id=id` (the update I need to do is to increase the object's `likes` by 1). What I have so far is, I can get the post like so:

```
self.post = $filter('filter')(self.posts, {id: id}, true);
self.post.likes = self.post.likes + 1;
```

but any idea where I go after getting this? (I currently have self.post is a variable. How would I replace the post inside `ctrl.posts` with `self.post` now?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(ctrl.posts, function(post, index){
    if(post.id == myId){
       post.likes++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash and the map function: [lodash map function](https://lodash.com/docs#map)

Comment: Hm, any way to do it with just AngularJS and JS?

Comment: loop through the elements in the array, if statement on id and then update the array item likes as necessary. Just not as tidy

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javscript. Do the following:

```js
var postIndex = ctrl.posts.map(function(item) {return item.id; }).indexOf(myId);
var foundPost = ctrl.posts[postIndex];
```